# mongodb .toArray vs .each (blocking vs async?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, loops

My question is which of the following is blocking and therefore not recommended for nodejs

1. `db.collection("allinfo").find({somekey: "someval"}).each(function(err, item){       //we get each item.... });`
2. `db.collection("allinfo").find({somekey: "someval"}).toArray(function(err, allitems){ //we get whole array.... });`

Which one should be preferred and when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the real difference here is sparse, and it's very much dependent on your situation.

```
db.collection("allinfo").find({somekey: "someval"})
```

The main there here is this ^. `find` opens a cursor, which isn't all that heavy. It's actually pretty fast -- the next part, using `toArray` or `each` is all reading the cursor.

In my experience, I use `each` when the count of the results is neglegent -- I don't need it. I use `toArray` when the length of the opened cursor is critical to the algorithm in question, or if I pass it along to another function that handles the array, instead of a function to handle each individual item.

Neither of these items are blocking, mongo runs natively in the async event loop with nodejs. You have to manually force the cursor to act sync, which isn't recommended.